# Fast way to check if a large set of file pairs are identical

Tags: c++, file, compare

I'm building a small sync utility in C++, for personal use mostly.

Imagine we have two directories 'A' and 'B' that will be synced. At some point, the new files from A will have to be copied to B. The logic I used so far was:

```
browse directory 'A'
for each 'A/afile'
    copy A/afile to B/afile
endfor
for each 'A/adirectory'
    recurse into 'A/adirectory'
endfor
```

This worked well, until I noticed that with the method above, ALL of the files from A are copied EVERY TIME to B. So, I would only like to perform the copy operation if A/afile and B/afile are different.

So, my question is, how can I compare them in a fast and cross-platform (hopefully) manner? Will something like computing MD5 checksums for each file be fast?

The point is, since the file comparison will be probably done for a large number of file pairs, I want something that is both reliable and fast. And by fast I mean that the 'heavy and time-consuming' task should be the actual copy operation and not the file checking.

PS. I also tried finding 'tricks', like comparing file size and modification times, with no success.

---

### EDIT

After taking into consideration the answers below, what I will finally go with to check if the two files are the same is:

```
if optimize_speed then
      if A/afile is newer then no (cause A/afile is the 'source' file)
      if B/afile is newer then compare byte-to-byte and decide 
else
      compare byte-to-byte and decide
end
```

Comment: Either with some framework like Qt (or any other that has filesystem module), or use system api. Compare modification times, don't compare sizes because you may change some lines in txt file and it's size wont change.

Comment: Just about all filesystems have a modification time-stamp. You can use that to check if the files in `A` are modifed after the corresponding files in `B`.

Comment: The problem with that is, if I copy A/afile to B/afile, then the modification time for 'B/afile' will be the time of the copy operation and not the modification time of A/afile. However, as a general solution, the program offers two sync modes: 'mirror' and 'append': Append already works fine, since I only copy files if they are newer. Mirror mode, however, should discard any changes made in B/afile, so the modification check wouldn't suffice, since B/afile could have been changed after A/afile. This is why I think file comparison is the way to go, unless ....... <to be continued>

Comment: <continue> unless there is an easier, cleaner and faster way. Also, I would like to avoid a depency as huge as Qt for such a small task. If that helps, you can find the source code here (look for the functions: copy_all_files(), copy_new_and_updated_files(), doMirrorSync(), doAppendSync() ). http://github.com/neoaggelos/synctool

Comment: @Status relying on modification times only is a really bad move. Especially on Windows when you copy a file its modification time is reset to the creation time. On Linux you can go around this but it's not that easy. Hashing is the best way to go here.

Comment: @neoaggelos Not really a problem, if the modification date of `A/afile` is later than the modification date of `B/afile` you know that `A/afile` have been modified after your last copying.

Comment: Maybe a side note, your pseudo-code is missing deletion of files from B which are no more present in A. Without this, the algorithm is not a sync.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the source code of the Linux `cmp` command-line tool. It is very well optimized, and running `cmp --silent file1 file2` has the exact semantics you seem to be after.

Comment: this is just the logic for the copy operation. of course i delete the files that are not present in A.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg this case is well-defined with the existing code. The problem starts when the modification time of B/afile is newer than A/afile

Comment: @Boris: I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: Roughly, `cmp --silent file1 file2` will **immediately** exit with code 1 if the files have a different time stamp, then it will start comparing byte-by-byte and immediately exit with status 1 if it finds different bytes, and only compare to the end if the files happen to be exactly the same. There is a lot of talk of calculating hashes or signatures in here, but it is guaranteed to be slower than just comparing bytes. If I were you, I would just use a script along the lines of `if cmp --silent file1 file2 ; then : ; else cp file1 file2 ; fi`

Comment: Comparing bytes could be faster, indeed. But I think all those read from file operations will cost a lot of time. I genuinely don't know how much they will slow down execution, or if they will at all.

Comment: There are many things you can do to speed up the comparison, for example, read in blocks of a size that nicely fits the processor cache etc. As I said several times, `cmp` is heavily optimized to do exactly that. I would altogether avoid coding it in C++ myself if there is any possibility to use an existing highly efficient tool.

Comment: The reason why `rsync` does things the way it does is that it is meant for syncing local with remote. There, comparing byte-by-byte is usually a very bad approach. You should really first figure out how often files will change, how big they are, how probable it is that the contents change but the size doesn't, how probable it is that the time stamp changes but the contents don't, etc. Only then you can have a solution that is "optimized" for your use case.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting point. I'll look into that as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any pair of synchronizable files `A` and `B`, the synchronization is required as long as the modification timestamps of both files are *not* equal.

The problem is ahem... timestamps are not part of the C++ standard... So, you'll either need to use something like Boost/Qt for cross-platform purposes.

The other way is, of course, ignore portability and take the solution for POSIX (p.d: remember to check for return values!):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <utime.h>

struct stat statOfA;
struct stat statOfB;
stat(pathOfA, &statOfA);
stat(pathOfB, &statOfB);

if(statOfA.st_mtime > statOfB.st_mtime) {
    // Sync! Then...
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);    // nullptr is prefered in C++11...

    struct timeval copys[] = { now, now };
    utimes(pathOfA, copys);
    utimes(pathOfB, copys);
}
```

**Edit**: You may see [GetSystemTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx), [SystemTimeToFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948(v=vs.85).aspx), [GetFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx), and [SetFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx) if you need to use the Windows API.

Comment: @Melebius: It's just an example of *how* to do it, and it's not intended to be directly compilable code, but anyway... (Editing).

Comment: WHEN a synchronization routine is triggered is not the same as "check if file pairs are identical". The second can be a chained event to the first but not necessarily. Either way this is not an answer to the question. -1 from me.

Comment: @rbaleksandar; Eh? But... did you read the title and not the question's body? The OP clearly states that he's searching for synchronization, and not just comparison of random files.

Comment: Hmm, changing the modification time of the new files. I hadn't thought of that. Doing this, as well as fixing the sync logic to take this into account should work. Thank you. I suppose the WinAPI probably offers similar functionality, so portability won't be affected. Thank you again, that's the way I'll go!

Comment: Yes, I read the title and the body of the question. The synch can be triggered by different time stamps however after that you still have to verify that there is actually something worth synching. The content of the files (byte-wise) is also essential. Imagine you modify a file (say change a string) and then reverse the change but save it anew. Modification timestamp changes however the content is the same.

Comment: @neoaggelos: Eh... just for the purpose of completeness. I made an edit that added an extra `utimes()` call at the end. This avoids an ugly race condition that can (and will...) occur. Anyway, I'm trying to remember how's this done in the WinAPI. I'll edit if I find something :)

Comment: @rbaleksandar: And do you think it's worth it to "make a hash" and all that overhead just for the possibility of that hack? My answer is still working, and, although your method may be optimized for such a situation, it provides the worst performance on most other (common) situations. **Edit**: The content may be the same, however it's technically still a modification :).

Comment: Yeah, I saw the edit. Don't worry about WinAPI, I'll just google it, it must be somewhere :)

Comment: Oh, by the way.. The reason I started writing the sync utility was because I hated all those overly complicated existing sync tools that require hundreds of options just to work. I wanted something that will simply sync my files without much hassle. So yeah, going ahead and making a hash beats that purpose.

Comment: Of course it is worth it. Jesus Christ, if synch services did things the way you suggest the amount of angry users would have skyrocketed...

Comment: @rbaleksandar: The conversation between you and me has become nonsense and thus, at least for me, it's over. **Edit**: Timestamps defeat checksums all day long (checksums take `O(n)` time based on the file's length, however timestamps have a constant `O(1)`)!

Comment: @neoaggelos: Yeah, I like the simple "do it yourself" approach too :). BTW, I found some functions that may help you; there links at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Of course. And I didn't blame the other sync services for doing what they have to do. It's just that I wanted something simple, so they didn't suit me. I didn't set out to change the way sync tools work, I set out to writing something that works for me and, hopefully, others that also want something simple

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's just for your usage @neoaggelos . What matters is is that relying on timestamps only is as unreliable as it gets. The computational complexity is important but so is the handling of the data itself - pointless copying of files is a waste of resources.

Comment: I'm all in for simplicity. If I can avoid the overhead of 1000 resource-heavy byte-to-byte comparisons of 10MB files, I'm willing to overwrite 2-3 same files. Seems to me like a good trade-off in speed, while also keeping things simple

Comment: Hash or byte-to-byte comparisons (cmp does just that which btw. is a Linux tool) are fast for small files. However copying a large amount of small files from one location to another is not. Compare copying 1000 small files of 1MB and a single 1000MB file. The second will be faster because the data is read and written in a much more efficient way. If you have SSD the situation improves of course. If you have a good old HDD based on the fragmentation of the files on a mechanical level spinning like crazy and moving the heads for reading and writing is a very intensive work.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: I'm still not conviced of your point... It's a perfectly valid optimization, but do we *really* have to sacrify the performance of almost all  the operation just for this? Wouldn't it be better to allow the user to select what technique to use depending on his/her knowledge of his/her data?

Comment: If I create a tool for comparing file pairs I would do my best to do it right. That's what I mean. At the end it's up to the OP what he/she wants to do. I'm talking here in terms of a correct solution.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: All of us are doing so. No answer so far has been "incorrect", but getting into "professional" and/or "correct" and/or "complete" stuff is outside of the range of this question, whose sole purpose is to help the OP to create a *simple* and *reliable* way for him/her to synchronize his/her own data.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be a tradeoff between speed and reliability. You want to try the fastet method first, then go to something more precise. Here is the algorithm followed by [fdupes](http://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes):

- compare file sizes
- => if different, then action (in your case, copy)
- compare MD5 signatures
- => if different, copy
- compare byte-by-byte
- => if different, copy
- else do nothing

Preparing this answer, I just learned that fdupes now add an intermediate step with partial MD5:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes

Comment: Comparing byte-by-byte and aborting immediately on a different byte is much faster than calculating signatures of any kind, _as long as both files are local_.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a bit of misinformation in every of the answers so far, here is my take on it:

1. If you really want to know that two files are identical, **you have to compare them byte by byte**. The chance that a checksum is the same but the files are different is very, very, *very* small, with a good checksum. However, computing a checksum is almost certainly slower than comparing file contents directly *when both files are local*. (The reason why `rsync` does not compare file contents is that it is meant for syncing remote files.)
2. If there is very little probability that you touch a file or otherwise change its time stamp *without changing its contents*, then go ahead and only compare time stamps. In some rare cases you will copy a file that has not changed, but you won't have to compare unnecessarily file contents.
3. Comparing sizes is not a good idea, esp. if you change some of the contents of the file.
4. Yes, comparing file contents means reading both files. There are ways to make this more efficient, but still, it will take time roughly linear to the smaller file size. If you really want to do it, consider using an existing command line tool like `cmp`.

Here is one way to invoke `cmp`:

```
cmp --silent file1 file2
```

This will tell you if two files are identical in contents (exit status 0) or different (exit status 1) or if something is amiss, like one of the two files does not exist (exit status 2). A bash script that takes two arguments and copies the first to the second if they are different:

```
if cmp --silent "$1" "$2"
then
    :
else
    cp "$1" "$2"
fi
```

**Take home message**: figure out what your use case is before implementing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing timestamps is only part of the solution but is far from the actually complete one. I strongly disagree with @KemyLand.

Imagine the following situation:

You have two files **F1** and **F2**. Both have the same content. Let's say modification timestamp is 14:00:00. Then you decide to change **F1** and save it. Modification timestamp changes for **F1** to 14:02:00. However before the next synch event you reverse the change in **F1** (for example you have deleted a string in there but decided to go back and add the string again). Modification timestamp changes again for **F1** to 14:06:00. However here we have a problem - even though the modification timestamp of **F1** is 14:06:00 and of **F2** - 14:00:00 - the **content** itself is the same!

Timestamp difference can however be a trigger to initiate a more in-depth check of the files that are to be synched. The content of the files however has to be checked and hashing is the best way to do that.

Calculating hashes for a large set of pairs of files can be a pain. However what you can do is scale your tool and try to optimize the usage of resources you have at your disposal. For example if you have 2 cores - use boths. If you have 8 cores - use all 8 and so on.

If you use timestamps as your only check you might end up needlessly copying files. Computing a hash for a pair of files is much better then blindly copying heaps of files just because a timestamp has changed but their contents have otherwise remained unchanged.

Use a combination of triggering events for more in-depth checks (timestamps changes, file size changes etc.) but always do hashing (or at least comparing using something like [cmp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp))to ensure you don't fall into one of the many scenarios (the one I mentioned above is just the tip of the iceberg) where you waste read and write access to your data. Calculating hashes for a large set of files is much more efficient compared to copying the data. Doesn't matter if you have a HDD or SSD as storage. The more files you have to move around the worse it gets when it comes to reads and writes. Size of each file also matters.

Comment: Again, hashing **is not the best way to compare files** when both files are local. Directly comparing the contents until the first difference is. Either way, there is a command line tool, `cmp`, which does exactly that when invoked as `cmp --silent file1 file2`.

Comment: Okay... How many times should I say it? **Hashes are too expensive and impredictable (in `O(n)` time)** compared to just checking a tiny and elegant timestamp. Anyway, do you *really* change your files and then undo your own changes *so* often?

Comment: @KemyLand I added things because I wasn't happy with the way I wrote my answer. Besides I have to read all the comments that appear and see what I can change so that it is more clear what I want to say. I presume you too look up stuff on the Internet to see if you can improve your answer. Hell, yesterday I added stuff to an answer I gave 1 year ago!

Comment: P.D: I'm proposing an edit, because I'm not sure how correct is (according to the site's rules) to directly and unnecesarily mention my username. It's not for any personal reason, because I have no problem with that, but rather to avoid further issues for everyone.

Comment: @KemyLand you just `touch file` and all of a sudden the timestamp is different even though the file (of unknown size) has not changed. Checking the timestamp is part of the solution, and the full solution depends on the use case.

Comment: @KemyLand There is absolutely no reason to not mention your user name. He could have just as well put a link to your answer.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: Yeah, it's too easy to ruin it up with *absolutely everything that happens in computing*. If you like, you can just `sudo rm --no-preserve-root -rf /` if you want to, no? The purpose of the program is not to protect against inefficient or inappropiate user by the user, but *to do what the user asks for*.

Comment: @Boris: I'm not offended with him writting down my username, but I don't think it brings anything positive to the answer's (this answer) quality and/or purpose.

Comment: @KemyLand And if you don't know what the "user" is really asking, how can you know what to do? ;) Maybe the user actually wants "a fast way to check if files are identical" and not just "a way to see if files have different time stamps"? :)

Comment: @KemyLand the "@" tiggers notification to the respective user. You get notifications for comments under the question and your answer. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125212). It is nothing "personal" as "personal attack". It is just a way to go with a discussion. This is how the meta works in stackoverflow.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: Eh... was that necessary? I think everyone here has understood that so far. And, I've already said it, keep my username in there if you want to, it's your answer after all :). I have no problems with it, more than the fact that it appears to affect a little bit the post's quality IMHO.

Comment: @Boris: You're right. So, I think it'll be better to query the user for the method he/she wants to operate his/her data with.

Comment: @KemyLand Final words on my behalf - it does indeed depend on what the OP understands by "identical". Based on the criteria the OP has contents of files might not be important though I really doubt that. Quote "I want something that is both RELIABLE AND FAST". You talk about speed, I talk about both reliability and speed.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: I didn't talked about realibility, speed, not to even mention performance. My only intention was to answer the OP's question, and what's what I did. And, as we are with quotes, let's remember that Unix is what it is because it is **simple**: "Let one program do one thing, and do it well" - Ken Thompson, Unix Philosophy. **Edit**: It just happens that all the methods presented in this page are "reliable," BTW.

Comment: @rbaleksandar Of course I want something reliable. I just want it to be as fast and simple as possible. If I wanted a sync utility with hashes and all that mumbo-jumbo I'd use an existing one, which is better than anything I can create by myself at my free time.

Comment: @KemyLand Haha, I just saw YOU edited my answer exactly in the part where I say I disagree with you...No further comment on this. Also the way you have changed it means I disagree with Boris, jbm and all answers that follow.